# onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('SignIn')} not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

Uncaught Error
Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Navigate, for some reason, doesn't work here, although it works everywhere besides this place. Could you please help out with the issue?

[image: Welcome Screen]

[image: App Navigation]

[image: Error]

Comment: please add code as TEXT not as an image - but it seems `navigation` is `undefined`

Comment: Oh, sorry I am new here. How do I define navigation?

Comment: as per [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation#example) I suspect

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss navigation props

add navigation here `WelcomeScreen({navigation})`

or you can use navigation hook like

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and use under your main component like

```
 const navigation = useNavigation();
```

It resolve your issue.